# configure: error: gmp.h header not found when building glpk

Tags: macos, build, configure, gmp, glpk

When trying to build glpk-4.61 on Mac OS X with

`./configure --with-gmp`

I get the following error message:

`checking gmp.h usability... no
 checking gmp.h presence... no
 checking for gmp.h... no
 configure: error: gmp.h header not found`

There were no issues installing GMP, and the header file gmp.h is present in /usr/local/include as expected.

Comment: Usually, there will be a file `config.log` where you can see how configure tried to determine if gmp.h was present and how that failed. That should tell you what you need to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.log told me no more than I already knew, that gcc can't find gmp.h (when trying to preprocess conftest.c). However, one can check which include paths are used by the c preprocessor with `cpp -v`, and it turned out that Xcode had made a mess of them. The solution was to run `xcode-select --install`, which added the usual include paths back.